# Is there any method to to pass filter to url in apche superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Can anyone let me know that can we show apache superset dashboard to a web page without using iframe and how to pass parameters to url?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Apache Superset-UI components in a custom web app.

https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui

Ultimately, connecting to Superset through the API and use the Superset-UI components to render the data.

But rendering as an IFrame is easier =].
You can also pass arbitrary url parameters and read their values in Jinja using a virtual dataset.